# Obtener un resultado con un solo input de números y operaciones Aritméticas - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, consola

Estoy tratando de hacer una "calculadora" con un solo input para cualquier operación y cualquier numero algo como esto: `(3 * 5 ( 5 / 6 ) 4 -2.9 )` = ?
como aplicación de consola en C#

Answer (score 1):

Existen librería que permiten el parseo de formulas matemáticas, existen muchas variadas que puedas aplicar

- [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/)

pero hay otras que se pueden evaluar

- [C# Eval Expression](https://eval-expression.net/)

veras que solo usa

```
int result = Eval.Execute<int>("X + Y", new { X = 1, Y = 2} );
```

definiendo la formula como `string` y pasando los valores por parámetro

- [NCalc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncalc/)

si revisas los test de github veras

```
var result = new Expression("2 * (3 + 5)").Evaluate();
```

son muy simples de usar

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar a la [*respuesta de Leandro*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/288880/77052):

C# no tiene ningún método nativo para realizar este tipo de operaciones (evaluar un string en runtime), sin embargo, implementar una función que lo haga no es muy complejo, con la ayuda de el método [`Compute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable.Compute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) de la clase [`DataTable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

```
/// <summary>
/// Método para evaluar una operación en tiempo de ejecución.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expression"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static Double Evaluar(String expression)
{
    //Creo un DataTable
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    //Realizo el cálculo..
    object result = table.Compute(expression, string.Empty);
    //Lo devuelvo convertido a Double
    return Convert.ToDouble(result);
}
```

Luego, basta con llamar a este método..

```
var result = Evaluar("(3 * 5 * ( 5 / 6 ) * 4 -2.9 )");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Va a producir la salida

> `47.1`

Dejo un [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfmcJc) del ejemplo funcionando

*Tome de base varias respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052640/in-c-sharp-is-there-an-eval-function) de [StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com)*